# Selecting rows based on Boolean values in a non dangerous way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is an easy question since it is so fundamental.  See - in R, when you want to slice rows from a dataframe based on some condition, you just write the condition and it selects the corresponding rows.  For example, if you have a condition such that only the third row in the dataframe meets the condition it returns the third row.  Easy Peasy.

In python, you have to use loc.  IF the index matches the row numbers then everything is great.  IF you have been removing rows or re-ordering them for any reason, you have to remember that - since loc is based on INDEX NOT ROW POSITION.  So if in your current dataframe the third row matches your boolean conditional in the loc statement - then it will retrieve the index with a number 3 - which could be the 50th row, rather than your current third row.  This seems to be an incredibly dangerous way to select rows, so I know I am doing something wrong.

So what is the best practice method of ensuring you select the nth row based on a boolean conditional?  Is it just to use loc and "always remember to use reset_index - otherwise if you miss it, even once your entire dataframe is wrecked"?  This can't be it.

Comment: If you create a Boolean _Series_ mask, then if you drop/rearrange rows from your DataFrame that Boolean Series will **still align on Index** so everything is fine. The caveat here being that you should generally have a DataFrame with a unique Index so the alignment is unambiguous if things change. The key here is that because this is `pandas` the Index is important, so you should be using a Boolean Series, not a Boolean array or a Boolean list where the assumption is that position matters.

Comment: iloc uses integer based indexing vs label

Comment: "in R, when you want to slice rows from a dataframe based on some condition, you just write the condition and it selects the corresponding rows" -- is this not true in pandas?  I find pandas' [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) functionality to be very robust and (more or less) functionally equivalent to logical/conditional selection in R/Stata/etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answers - I don't think iloc is what I am looking for because with iloc you can't do this  df.iloc[df.ColumnX==someValue,:].  If you try that you get an error.   Alollz, can you please elaborate on your answer.  It FEELS right, but I don't understand it.  Why would index still work if you are moving around and dropping rows?  I have gotten error messages where I slice some rows out and then forget that and then try and return - say  - the third row.  The error message tells me that index 3 is missing, or words to that effect.  Why a Boolean Series?

Comment: Alollz - your comment pointed me in the right direction.  I read around and I think I get it.  By using a Boolean indexer you are actually using a series, and the series has its own index, which will match the index of the dataframe.  So using a Boolean Series, it doesn't pick the third row as being true, it picks the INDEX of the third row in the Boolean Series, which of course will match the correct row in the DataFrame.

Comment: Alollz - I can't credit your comment as the answer, but if you paste it as an answer I will select it as the best.  Thanks to everyone for their help

Answer (score 0):

Use iloc instead of loc for integer based indexing:

```
data = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[1, 2, 3])
df
```

Dataset:

```
    A   B   C
1   1   4   7
2   2   5   8
3   3   6   9
```

Label based index

```
df.loc[1]
```

Results:

```
A    1
B    4
C    7
```

Integer based:

```
df.iloc[1]
```

Results:

```
A    2
B    5
C    8
```